# Recursive function in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make a recursive function and pass it to view to build a category, sub-category in laravel 5.2   and how to create  route and view and contrller for this code  ..... this is my code ..can anyone help me ?

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','123');
mysql_select_db('test');
 
 $qry="SELECT * FROM treeview_items";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);
 $arrayCategories = array();
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 { 
     $arrayCategories[$row['id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "name" =>$row['name']);   
 }
 
 function createTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) {

foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) {

 
if ($currentParent == $category['parent_id']) {                          
    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ul class='tree'> "; 

    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";

    echo '<li> <a href="#">'.$category['name'].'</a > ';

    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }

    $currLevel++; 

    createTree ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);

    $currLevel--;               
    }   

}

if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ul> ";

}   
?>

<?php
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
 {
?>
<?php 
createTree($arrayCategories, 0); ?>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Go through the documentation. You will get almost all of it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is here: https://github.com/etrepat/baum

this will automatically work for.